# Is there a guide on how to code custom blocks for NXT?

Tags: mindstorms, nxt

The answer to a previous question pointed to "custom blocks for NXT". I am not talking about creating "My Blocks" in the "Custom Palette", but code blocks that can be imported into LEGO Mindstorms NXT.

Are there tools to code these custom blocks available to the public? Where can I get them?

Answer (score 2):

Custom blocks are created using National Instruments LabView software. The instructions for how to do this are still available at https://download.ni.com/evaluation/mindstorms/NXT_Creating_MINDSTORMS_Blocks.pdf.

After some digging, I was able to find https://forums.ni.com/t5/NI-Labs-Toolkits/NI-LabVIEW-for-LEGO-MINDSTORMS-LabVIEW-Module-for-LEGO/ta-p/3516439?profile.language=en which looks like it still has download links that work.

I haven't actually tried installing and running anything though.

Comment: The link for LabView is a dead end but I found it here: http://www.ni.com/download/labview-development-system-7.1/3578/en/